# compiling sass (using compass) via 'watch'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass, compass-sass

What is the difference between using `sass --watch` and `compass watch` to poll for changes in sass files and compile?

Also, I'm doing this in an RoR app, and sass compiles automatically (is this the default?).  When would I need to use these commands?

Answer (score 2):

Doing `sass --watch` will just compile everything using bare Sass, while doing `compass --watch` is (in a simplified way) the same as doing `sass --compass --watch`.
If you just do `sass --watch`, every compass related import, such as `@import compass/css3/` per example, will not be recognized.

Using Compass in general offers a lot of helpers regarding assets paths, mixins and so forth. If you need more information I recommand looking at the Compass [official website](http://compass-style.org/).

Comment: So does that mean if I use Compass mixins in my code, I will have to use "compass compile" to compile my code if not the vanilla sass compile will not recognize compass mixins?

Comment: It's not the mixins it won't recognize, it's the `@import "compass"` but yes.